# When to update the qunatity in Ecommerce

Tags: database, stock

When i can update the quantity in E Commerce, Suppose there is 1 item remaining and two customer made add to bag the same item. So how i can update this and which customer can buy the particular item, whether i have to update while add to bag or after payment.
Please help me to find this idea

Answer (score 0):

Better to update while adding to the cart, and if customer is not doing checkout then you can remove the items from their cart , time is as per the availability of your stock